# Run remote backup on regulary base

Tags: macos, backup, plist, launchd

I wrote a shell script which checks if a remote server is reachable.
If it is reachable, it runs via ssh a command at a different server.
After that, it does some rsync tasks.

Everything works well, so I wrote a plist-files to run the whole staff every 4 hours.

What's work:

- The script is triggered as expected (I saw it at stdout-file).
- launchctl start myjob works fine too (I saw it at stdout-file).

My problem:

If the job starts during the macbook sleeps, the ping works well, but the ssh command doesn't come back. The command is executed at the server, but the script stops there.
If I kill the process with the ssh-command the script finish well.

What can I do to get more information. What could be the error? What could be another solution (Timemachine is not an option, because I want a general readable backup)?

Mac OS BigSur 11.4 M1-Chip

Here my plist-files

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>de.stanetz.backup</string>
                <key>Program</key>
                <string>/usr/local/sbin/remoteBackup.nsh</string>
                <key>RunAtLoad</key>
                <false/>
                <key>StandardOutPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/launch-stdout.log</string>
                <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/launch-stderr.log</string>
                <key>Debug</key>
                <true/>
                <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
                <array>
                        <dict>
                                <key>Hour</key>
                                <integer>9</integer>
                                <key>Minute</key>
                                <integer>15</integer>
                        </dict>
                </array>
                <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
                <integer>360</integer>
                <key>TimeOut</key>
                <integer>360</integer>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

Update: I changed the ssh command to `ssh -vv pooh 'echo "this runs remotely"' >/tmp/so-debug.log 2>&1`. Which works fine.
If I call `debug1: Sending command: /usr/local/sbin/handleBackupPlatte.nsh open` via ssh (which runs 10 seconds),  the complete shell-script finished, but I found in the log:

```
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 15.
```

The duration of time till the remote-script finished seems to be the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this runs remotely"
sleep 10
echo "for 10 seconds"
```

shows the effect. But I can't make the script faster :-/ Any ideas, except to send the ssh command to background?

Update 2: It seems that every network call which needs 10 seconds will hang and never finished if the mac book is in sleep-state.

Comment: The problem almost certainly has something to do with what ssh and/or the remote command are doing. I'd recommend testing variations like running a minimal remote command (e.g. `ssh somehost 'echo "this runs remotely"'`) to isolate what's involved in causing the problem.

Comment: It's hard to test if it works when I sit before the mac. And the remote program is finished. I can't find any ssh connections. But I will change the ssh to "ssh -vv" perhaps this gives more information.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it seems that every remote call which doesn't finish in a few (<10) seconds is a problem :-/. Any ideas? Is it forbidden that a launchd-job runs for a longer time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch to a different approach. I install sleepwatcher which notify if a macbook is wake up. Furthermore, I combined this with a script which ensures that not on every wake up the backup is running.
Here the script

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
set -eu


## RETURN_CODES
# 11 -> BACKUP_ALREADY_RUNNING
# 12 -> NIGHT -> No Backup
# 13 -> Last backup is too young.

#VARIABLES
LOCK_FILE="/tmp/.backup.lock"
LAST_SUCCESS_FILE="/var/log/.backup.last_success"
RUN_CONTROL="/var/log/throttle.log"
MIN_BACKUP_AGE=240

cleanup() {
        exitCode=$?
        date +"Exit Throttle at  %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S with $exitCode" >> ${RUN_CONTROL}    
        
        if [[ "$exitCode" -ne 11 ]]; then
                rm ${LOCK_FILE}
        fi
        echo "$(tail -n 100 ${RUN_CONTROL})" > ${RUN_CONTROL}
        
        exit $exitCode  
}

trap cleanup EXIT

test -e ${LOCK_FILE} && echo "${LOCK_FILE} exists" && exit 11
touch ${LOCK_FILE}

hour=$(date +%H)

if [ "$hour" -gt 22 ] || [ "$hour" -lt 7 ]; then
    exit 12
fi

test -e "$(find ${LAST_SUCCESS_FILE} -mmin -${MIN_BACKUP_AGE})" && exit 13 || true

/usr/local/sbin/remoteBackup.nsh
echo "$(tail ${LAST_SUCCESS_FILE})" > ${LAST_SUCCESS_FILE}
date >> ${LAST_SUCCESS_FILE}
```

and the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/opt/homebrew/sbin/sleepwatcher</string>
                <string>-V</string>
                <string>-w /usr/local/sbin/throttledBackup.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/sleepwatcher-stdout.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>               
    <string>/var/log/sleepwatcher-stderr.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```